# subseting columns from a data frame in R

Tags: r, csv, subset

I have a huge data frame, but I only need some columns to work on. my code:

```
outcome_data<- read.csv("dat.csv", colClasses= "character")
interested_data<- outcome_data[, c(1, 2, 7, 11, 17, 23)]
```

is giving me this error when I run it in my function:

> *Error in data.frame(list(Provider.Number = c("450690", "450358", "450820",  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 370, 0*

But works fine in interactive mode.
Any other alternative? or how to fix this?

Comment: Could you show the `str(outcome_data)` if the number of columns are not too big.

Comment: There is something you are not showing us. Anyway, you might want to read only the columns of interest. `help("read.table")` explains how to skip columns during import.

Comment: Is R even importing the data in non-interactive mode? Put a logical check before you create `interested_data`.

Answer (score 0):

data.table:::fread(data, **select**, ...)

---

**select** Vector of column names or numbers to keep, drop the rest.
etc.

```
fread(data, select=c("A","D")) 
fread(data, select=c(1,4))
```